# Sudden Disappearance of Data in Amplify Admin UI, Despite Accessibility via AppSync and GraphQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I've run into a bit of a puzzling situation with my project using AWS Amplify's DataStore. Up until recently, everything was cruising along smoothly. I've been using DataStore for all my CRUD operations and subscriptions, and it's been great. But, out of the blue, I've hit a snag: the content that should be visible in the Amplify Admin UI has vanished into thin air.

What's Going On:

Previously, data visibility and management through the Amplify Admin UI were spot on. Now, despite no changes on my end, the data is playing a game of hide and seek – it's nowhere to be seen in the Admin UI.
The twist in the tale is that when I query the same data using GraphQL through AppSync, it's right there, as expected. So, the data is definitely there and intact, it's just the Admin UI that's giving me the silent treatment. Since, I am using DataStore, my application i.e React neither fetches nor performs CRUD operation anymore.

Steps I've Tried:

Looked for the data in the Amplify Admin UI, particularly in the DataStore models section.
Noticed that it's like a ghost town – no data in sight.
Switched over to querying via AppSync with GraphQL.

What I'm Expecting:

Ideally, the data managed by Amplify DataStore should be consistently visible and accessible both in the Amplify Admin UI and via AppSync/GraphQL queries.

A Bit More Info:

Everything was smooth sailing until this issue popped up. No major changes were made recently that I can think of. It's a bit like someone flipped a switch and the data just disappeared from the Admin UI.

PS: I haven't recieved any failed to sync error in the ADMIN UI

[image]

1. Re-deploying the backend.